# How to hyperlink a table column value in a data table using angular7?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my application I am fetching the data in a data table. The application front end is running on angular7. Now I want some of the column values should have a link and click on the link a new component will be displayed.
Example::

```
Column1           Column2     Column3
value with Link
```

How I can Implement this scenario using angular7?

I am going through the routing docs in
https://angular.io/guide/router

But does not able to map it with my current requirement.

Comment: How are you displaying your data table?

Comment: I Am using Angular Material to display the data table.                                        <table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="changeSort($event)">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="column1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Column1 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.coulmn1}} </td>
      </ng-container>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right you are using Angular Material data table, isn't it?

If so, try this:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="prop">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prop Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <a routerLink="/your-link">{{element.prop}}</a>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: For the link I need to create a new component right.

Comment: No, just wrap your value with the routerLink

Comment: I think I need to map the link in router.module.ts. Otherwise getting an error ::                             Cannot match any routes

Comment: How do i send query parameter with the routerLink?

Comment: @stumbler, you can refer the solution provided by me in this regard

Comment: How would you do just a single row say the third row but not rows: 1..2 and 4..8? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to add a link to the whole row?

Answer (score 1):

> ***Solution 1: Using Angular Material Table***

If you are specifically working with Angular Material and find it tricky to add the hyperlink in data table column then following solution would help

**.ts file**

```
import { ProductService } from './../data-service/data-service-product/product.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { IProduct } from '../models/IProduct';
import { MatPaginator }  from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  products: IProduct[];
  filteredProducts: any[];
  subscriptionVariable: Subscription;

  displayedColumns = ['title', 'price', 'action'];
  dataSource =  new MatTableDataSource();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private productDataService: ProductService) {
    this.subscriptionVariable = this.productDataService.getAll().subscribe(
      p => this.dataSource.data = this.filteredProducts = this.products = p as IProduct[] );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-lifecycle-interface
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptionVariable.unsubscribe();
  }   

}
```

**.interface**

```
export interface IProduct {
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    price: number;
    title: string;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p>
  <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">
    New Product
  </a>
</p>
<p>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
</p>

    <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Title </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Price </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Star Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action" >
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Action </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <a [routerLink] ="['/admin/products/', element.key]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >Edit</a>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [length]="5" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

---

> ***Solution 2: Using html table***

---

Using normal html you can create your own table and then add the functionality accordingly

**component.html file**

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts">
          <td>
            {{ product.title}}
          </td>

          <td>
            {{ product.price}}
          </td>

          <td>
            <a [routerLink] ="['/admin/products/', product.key]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**

> Final Result

**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an EMBEDDED link within a larger text, the above won't work for you.
This is what worked for me - you can use innerHTML attribute binding:

```
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="element.name">
    </td>
```

...and the text will remain text, with the link becoming a link assuming the wrapping anchor html tag is present, otherwise you can write a function in your .ts code to auto-wrap links as follows (presumes a single link as ' http' followed by a space or EOF):

```
  addHyperlink(txtLinkSansAnchor: string) {
enter code here
    const srchVal = ' http';
    var retVal = txtLinkSansAnchor; // init to self
    hyperlinkProtocol: string = '<a target="_blank" href="----">----</a>';
    if (txtLinkSansAnchor.includes(srchVal)) {
      var startPos = txtLinkSansAnchor.indexOf(srchVal) + 1;
      var endPos = txtLinkSansAnchor.indexOf(' ', startPos + 5);
      if (endPos < startPos) {
        endPos = txtLinkSansAnchor.length;
      }
      var replStringOrig = txtLinkSansAnchor.substring(startPos, endPos);
      var replStringNew = hyperlinkProtocol.split('----').join(replStringOrig);
      var txtLinkWithAnchor = txtLinkSansAnchor.replace(replStringOrig, replStringNew);
      retVal = txtLinkWithAnchor;
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

...and then your html template code will look as follows:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="addHyperlink(element.name)">
</td>
```